# I need to create a bracketed tree given a parse history

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, parsing, nltk, parse-tree

I am trying to create a bracketed tree given the following parse history in Python 3.5:

```
parse = [('S', 0), ('NP', 1), ('Det', 0), 'scan', ('N', 0), 'scan', ('VP', 1), ('V', 4), 'scan', ('NP', 2), ('NP', 0), ('PN', 1), 'scan', ('NP', 1), ('Det', 0), 'scan', ('N', 3), 'scan']
```

The sentence is: 'the man showed Mary the dog'

The grammar used is:

```
grammar = {'S': [['NP', 'VP']],
               'NP': [['PN'], ['Det', 'N'], ['NP', 'NP']],
               'VP': [['V'], ['V', 'NP']],
               'PN': [['John'], ['Mary'], ['Bill']],
               'Det': [['the'], ['a']],
               'N': [['man'], ['woman'], ['drill sergeant'], ['dog']],
               'V': [['slept'], ['cried'], ['assaulted'],
                     ['devoured'], ['showed']]}
```

The format for each tuple in the list is that the first item in the tuple is a key in the dictionary which contains a list of possible rules and the second item in the tuple is the index of the rule in the list returned given grammar[key][index] whenever 'scan' appears it means that the

The output needs to be:

```
(S(NP(Det the)(N man))(VP (V showed)(NP (NP(PN Mary))(NP(Det the)(N dog)))))
```

The best output I've gotten so far is:

```
(S
NP)
VP)
(NP
Det)
N)
(Det
the)
(N
man)
(VP
V)
NP)
(V
showed)
(NP
NP)
NP)
(NP
PN)
(PN
Mary)
(NP
Det)
N)
(Det
the)
(N
dog)
```

Given the following code:

```
for item in parse:
    if item != 'scan':
        print("(" + item[0])
        for rule in grammar[item[0]][item[1]]:
            print(rule + ")")
```

PLEASE HELP!

Thank you

Comment: How did you create the parse history? The best solution would be to build the tree as you are parsing, instead of the list you assembled (or in addition to it). Once you have a tree, converting it into a string will automatically produce all the brackets.

Comment: If you really can't do that, focus on building a tree by interpreting the parse history, and again the conversion to string will be trivial.

Comment: @alexis What form should I use to to interpret the parse history?

Comment: I meant, build a tree by following the instructions of the parse history, e.g., use `nltk.Tree` and build it up step by step (perhaps recursively). It looks like a depth-first transversal. You didn't say where they came from, though. Your grammar and parse history formats seem like a pain to work with.

Comment: @alexis Yeah, they are. What do you recommend as a different format?

Comment: Build the tree as you go along.

Comment: And start by using the NLTK's grammar format. Then you can use the NLTK tools with it too.

Comment: @alexis I don't understand what you mean by build the tree as you go along. Can you point me to something that shows the NLTK grammar format?

Comment: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html

Comment: A tree is a data structure, e.g. a list containing other lists (the branches) that contain more lists; not a string with parentheses. Keep this in mind as you read the chapter.

Comment: @alexis I've figured out how to create the subtrees but I can't figure out how to add these trees together to get the full parse tree. I've read the chapter but nothing really helps.

Comment: A tree is a list containing other trees, or strings: `t1 = Tree("Det", [ "the" ]); t2 = Tree("NP", [t1, "dog"])`. Etc. Write some code (complete enough to be understandable) and ask a new question about it.